# sapui5- How to change default action on panel icon click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I am using sapui5 panel, and I allow to expandable that it will show default icon on toolbar ">", when I click on it, it will togglecollapse, but I want to add some action on it.

Here is the panel and there is one icon at the end.
Any idea to override function, customize function, or add some action on that icon when we click on it?

My purpose is, I want to add warning message before panel is collapsed, if I click "yes" to confirm, it can collapse, "No" it still the same, do nothing.

> [image: Here are the image of panel and icon]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `attachExpand` ?
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Panel.html#attachExpand

I'm still new to this ui5 :p

Here we go

```
        var panel = new sap.m.Panel("panel-1", {
            headerText:"Test Panel",
            expandable: true
        });
        panel.setExpanded = function (bExpanded) {
            if (bExpanded === this.getExpanded()) {
                return this;
            }
            //may need to reset this later
            this.setProperty("expanded", bExpanded, true);
            if (!this.getExpandable()) {
                return this;
            }

            //add custom logic here
            if(bExpanded){

            }
            //custom logic

            this._getIcon().$().attr("aria-expanded", this.getExpanded());
            this._toggleExpandCollapse();
            this._toggleCssClasses();

            this.fireExpand({ expand : bExpanded });
            return this;
        };
```

Comment: hi Ryan, this event work fine when the toggle collapse is completed, but I want to add some action before it collapse the panel, like warning message before collapse.
Any idea to improve.

Comment: @Bunchureach I see, I would try override the prototype chain Panel.prototype.setExpanded, by looking at the source code https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/Panel.js. I believe your custom stuffs can be added before this.fireExpand()

Comment: I don't understand yet, but it seem like you want me to change the default prototype chain code. If so, maybe it will work, but it may affect to other function that call to the same function "setExpanded", for me, I just want to do it to only panel icon. Any other idea?

Comment: @Bunchureach if you limit the override to one single instance, the impact should be small imho

Comment: That code work well and I change some of my coding. Now it works, thanks